# How to determine which event type triggered a workflow (create/change)?

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have a list workflow which triggers when list item is created or changed.

How to determine which of two events has triggered the workflow?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to do an If Item:Created equals Item:Modified do X else do Y.

When an item is created, the created and modified dates are idential. When an item is modified, they are different.

Comment: The same solution described here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53184/how-to-get-the-event-trigger-of-a-sharepoint-workflow?rq=1. It is not a good solution. I have seen cases when Item:Created and Item:Modified were the same (when create and save page in Publishing Portal).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use PirateEric's suggestion of triggering off Item:Created and Item:Modified, you could create a NewItem yes/no column that defaults to yes and is changed to no by the workflow when it's first run. If you're using the Created/Changed differentiation to determine whether to send an alert email, you could call the column SendAlertEmail. You could then create an InfoPath form that doesn't give users the option to change that field.